# PIC18F67K40 - Failed to get device ID

Tags: pic, microchip, mplab

I am using PIC18F67K40 and PICKIT3 with MPLAB 8.92V for programming. But I am getting error:

> Failed to get device ID

I have attached schematic snap of MCLR circuitry. I am able to program other board using the same kit, so I am not suspecting malfunctioning of kit.

So far I have tried below:

1. Using external supply for target
2. Setting different voltage in settings of MPLAB

Update: I was able to program the chip using @Mike suggestion, Now i am getting Following Error/Warning for another chip of same model

MPLAB X has detected that the device’s low voltage configuration bit is set to OFF but the tool is set to low voltage programming and cannot program the device. To correct this:

> 1. Change the tool’s programming option to use High Voltage programming.
> 2. Change the device’s configuration bit to use low voltage (LVP=ON). Program the device using high voltage to reprogram the device’s
>      configuration bit.
> 3. Change the tool’s programming option back to Low Voltage programming for subsequent programming of the device.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MCU_DEVICE_FLAGS>
  <DEVICE>
    <DEVICE_NAME>P18F67K40</DEVICE_NAME>
    <SETTINGS>
      <COUNT>43</COUNT>
      <SETTING0>
        <NAME>External Oscillator Mode Selection</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>EC (external clock) above 8 MHz: PFM set to high power</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING0>
      <SETTING1>
        <NAME>Default Power-up Value (COSC)</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>EXTOSC operating per FEXTOSC bits (device manufacturing default)</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING1>
      <SETTING2>
        <NAME>Clock Out Enable bit</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>CLKOUT function is disabled</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING2>
      <SETTING3>
        <NAME>Clock Switch Enable</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Writing to NOSC and NDIV is allowed</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING3>
      <SETTING4>
        <NAME>Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Fail-Safe Clock Monitor enabled</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING4>
      <SETTING5>
        <NAME>Master Clear (MCLR) Enable</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>If LVP = 0, MCLR pin is MCLR</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING5>
      <SETTING6>
        <NAME>Power-up Timer Enable bit</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Power up timer disabled</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING6>
      <SETTING7>
        <NAME>Low-Power BOR</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>ULPBOR disabled</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING7>
      <SETTING8>
        <NAME>Brown-out Reset Enable bits</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Brown-out Reset enabled , SBOREN bit is ignored</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING8>
      <SETTING9>
        <NAME>Brown Out Reset Voltage selection bits</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Brown-out Reset Voltage (VBOR) set to 2.45V</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING9>
      <SETTING10>
        <NAME>ZCD Disable bit</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>ZCD disabled. ZCD can be enabled by setting the ZCDSEN bit of ZCDCON</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING10>
      <SETTING11>
        <NAME>PPSLOCK bit One-Way Set Enable bit</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>PPSLOCK bit can be cleared and set only once</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING11>
      <SETTING12>
        <NAME>Stack Full/Underflow Reset Enable bit</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Stack full/underflow will cause Reset</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING12>
      <SETTING13>
        <NAME>Background Debug</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Background debugger disabled</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING13>
      <SETTING14>
        <NAME>Extended Instruction Set Enable bit</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Extended Instruction Set and Indexed Addressing Mode disabled</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING14>
      <SETTING15>
        <NAME>WDT Period Selection</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Divider ratio 1:65536</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING15>
      <SETTING16>
        <NAME>WDT operating mode</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>WDT enabled regardless of sleep</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING16>
      <SETTING17>
        <NAME>WDT Window Select bits</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>window always open (100%): software control</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING17>
      <SETTING18>
        <NAME>WDT input clock selector</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Software Control</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING18>
      <SETTING19>
        <NAME>Write Protection Block 0</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Block 0 (000800-003FFFh) not write-protected</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING19>
      <SETTING20>
        <NAME>Write Protection Block 1</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Block 1 (004000-007FFFh) not write-protected</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING20>
      <SETTING21>
        <NAME>Write Protection Block 2</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Block 2 (008000-00BFFFh) not write-protected</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING21>
      <SETTING22>
        <NAME>Write Protection Block 3</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Block 3 (00C000-00FFFFh) not write-protected</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING22>
      <SETTING23>
        <NAME>Write Protection Block 3</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Block 4 (010000-013FFFh) not write-protected</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING23>
      <SETTING24>
        <NAME>Write Protection Block 3</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Block 5 (014000-017FFFh) not write-protected</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING24>
      <SETTING25>
        <NAME>Write Protection Block 3</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Block 6 (018000-01BFFFh) not write-protected</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING25>
      <SETTING26>
        <NAME>Write Protection Block 3</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Block 7 (01C000-01FFFFh) not write-protected</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING26>
      <SETTING27>
        <NAME>Configuration Register Write Protection bit</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Configuration registers (300000-30000Bh) not write-protected</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING27>
      <SETTING28>
        <NAME>Boot Block Write Protection bit</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Boot Block (000000-0007FFh) not write-protected</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING28>
      <SETTING29>
        <NAME>Data EEPROM Write Protection bit</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Data EEPROM not write-protected</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING29>
      <SETTING30>
        <NAME>Scanner module Enable</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Scanner module is available for use, SCANMD bit can control the module</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING30>
      <SETTING31>
        <NAME>Low Voltage Programming Enable bit</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Low voltage programming enabled. MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR. MCLRE configuration bit is ignored</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING31>
      <SETTING32>
        <NAME>UserNVM Program Memory Code Protection bit</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>UserNVM code protection disabled</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING32>
      <SETTING33>
        <NAME>DataNVM Memory Code Protection bit</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>DataNVM code protection disabled</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING33>
      <SETTING34>
        <NAME>Table Read Protection Block 0</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Block 0 (000800-003FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING34>
      <SETTING35>
        <NAME>Table Read Protection Block 1</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Block 1 (004000-007FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING35>
      <SETTING36>
        <NAME>Table Read Protection Block 2</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Block 2 (008000-00BFFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING36>
      <SETTING37>
        <NAME>Table Read Protection Block 3</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Block 3 (00C000-00FFFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING37>
      <SETTING38>
        <NAME>Table Read Protection Block 4</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Block 4 (010000-013FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING38>
      <SETTING39>
        <NAME>Table Read Protection Block 5</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Block 5 (014000-017FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING39>
      <SETTING40>
        <NAME>Table Read Protection Block 6</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Block 6 (018000-01BFFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING40>
      <SETTING41>
        <NAME>Table Read Protection Block 7</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Block 7 (01C000-01FFFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING41>
      <SETTING42>
        <NAME>Boot Block Table Read Protection bit</NAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>Boot Block (000000-0007FFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks</DESCRIPTION>
      </SETTING42>
    </SETTINGS>
  </DEVICE>
</MCU_DEVICE_FLAGS>
```

[image]

Comment: Try to disable LVP in your source code.

Comment: Actually, I use MicroC So i need to update those in settings right?

Comment: @Mike I am able to program the second chip now

Comment: great!! With MikroC you could not set the config bits in code. What was your problem?

Comment: I have 2 resistor series on PGM and PGD. They were not soldered.

Comment: @Mike I am able to dump a small blink led code and it working and when i dump another different code nothing works. I am suspecting configuration bit settings. Can u share the configuration bit settings i need to follow for PIC18F67K40 ?

Comment: Post your actual configuration settings. Preferably in a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98771/discussion-between-mightybeard007-and-mike).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PIC18F67k40 is not supported by MPLAB 8.92 (it's pretty old)
You had to update your IDE to MPLABX (v5.25)

In your source code there should be a configuration section:

```
#pragma config LVP = OFF
#pragma config  ...
```

Comment: The thing is that, before going for the board design we have tested the EVM (demo board) of the PIC18F67k40  and it was detected and testing was done and only after we went in to board designing.

Comment: If you are able to program the first chip, your tool works fine. I guess there is a different problem with the other chip. Maybe hardware. That should be a different question in a new thread.

Comment: i have updated my configuration bits on the original answer